# Need Generic Transpose script

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

[image]

Following is table for particular transaction id

```
TransactionId FirstName Lastname ContactNo ....
    27           John      A        123
    27           Mark      B        124
```

I need out put like

```
TransactionId FirstName Lastname ContactNo FirstName Lastname ContactNo ....
   27           John       A        123       Mark      B        124
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT @col_list = Stuff((SELECT ',id = max(case when id = '
                             + Cast(id AS VARCHAR(50))
                             + ' then id end), mobilenumber = max(case when id = '
                             + Cast(id AS VARCHAR(50))
                             + ' then mobilenumber  end)'                                
                      FROM   [dbo].[TransactionContact] where  transactionid in (137103,137102)

                      ORDER  BY id
                      FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
```

EXEC('select '+@col_list+' from [dbo].[TransactionContact]')

This works  as per above, but brings contact for all transactionid in same row instead different row